# Old ColdfusionHow to create a ASP.net login page using variables

Tags: asp.net

I am a true newbie. I need your advice since I have a poor understanding of the creation of a login page using ASP.net

I come from ColdFusion. They use Session Variable that are used to monitor the session  status located at the  the header or footer.

What will be the equivalent in ASP.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329(v=vs.140).aspx

That will help. But you can do the same way using Session variables like you do in ColdFusion but that is not recommended.